# Company backend for words inside the buffer

Tags: company-mode

### Setup:

GUI version GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-07-25 on KAEL
[Compiled from EmacsW64.](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/)

Company, using the latest version of Company  from MELPA

Windows 7 x64 bit.

### Situation:

Propably I'm missing something. I couldn't figure it out with Google. After reorganizing my `.emacs.d`, I noticed I don't get any completion from buffers.

For example, I'm typing in the buffer `foobarsentence`.

And then start a new line below that, and typing `fooba`, I expected to get company completion suggestion that shows `foobarsentecene`, and I just need to press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>RET</kbd>.

But I see nothing. I couldn't find any company backend that's responsible for words-in-buffer completion. Anyone knows which company backend I mean?

Comment: If the problem occurred after you reorganized your init file, you should probably consult your old version to see what you may have missed when reorganizing.

Comment: I already thought of that. I moved things here and there, that I couldn't find it back. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not a company backend, but you can get this behavior easily by turning on [HippieExpand mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand) and integrating it with Company by adding `company-complete` to `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller thanks for your tip! It's appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is `company-dabbrev`, named after the [dabbrev](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html) command bound to `M-/`.

Comment: It is working with `M-/`, but not what I meant it. I added it to the list: `(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-dabbrev t)`, which is not working as given in the example above. When I'm typing something, I get a popup with the completion suggestions. The completions from `company-dabbrev` are missing. So I guess I miss some spot here?

Comment: There's also `company-dabbrev-code` for things outside comments and strings, maybe that's what you're after.

Comment: No, `company-dabbrev` works fine, but the issue is that I would get that into the completion popup window. Any suggestion, in order to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you marking this answer as accepted, then open a new question that's essentially the same?

Comment: Because your answer targets the company backend that's responsible for complete the words that are currently in the buffer. The another question targets how feed the popup completion from a backend.